# solving 1st order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-y-5}{x+y-1}$$

the question says to use $x = u + a$ and $y = V(u) + b$, where $a,b$ should be determined. I'm assuming that $a = 3, b = -2$ and using this and noting $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx} = V'(u)$$ I get $$V'(u) = \frac{u-V(u)}{u+V(u)}$$

question: Is what I done so far correct? 
question: How do I proceed from here?

Comment: the equation is homogeneous equation, set $V = u w(u)$ and turn it into linear equation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is a good approach. We have:

$$X = X + h \\ Y = y + k$$

Substituting and solving for the constants yields (as you show):

$$k = 3, h = -2$$

We now have:

$$\dfrac{dY}{dX} = \dfrac{Y-X}{Y+X}$$

Make the substitution:

$$Y = vX \implies Y' = v + X \dfrac{dv}{dX}$$

Substituting this in, we have the separable equation (so we integrate):

$$\int \dfrac{1+v}{1+v^2}~dv = - \int \dfrac{1}{X} ~ dX$$

This yields:

$$\tan^{-1} v + \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(1 + v^2) = -\ln X + c$$

All that is left is to substitute for $v = \dfrac{Y}{X}$, $X = x -h = x+2$ and $Y = y-k = y-3$ and simplify.